# Comparing values in an array using a for each function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an assignment to perform some specific tasks on an array using a for each function. I have everything working except for the last one - I'm close but the first and last values being returned are incorrect.

In the isNextGreater function I need to take the value of an element in the array and compare it to the next element. If the value of the element is < the value of the next element I need to return a -1. If the value is greater I need to return 1. The last element needs to return its original value as there is nothing to compare it to.

When the function runs it returns the correct value for [1] and [2] but [0] returns its original value and [3] returns 1.

I know I'm close but an missing something! Could someone give me a hint as to what I am over looking?

Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Functions: forEach </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>

// the zeros array
var zeros = [0, 0, 0, 0];

// your code here

//Function to display the contents of the Array.

function showArray (value, index, theArray) {
console.log("Array[" + index + "]" + ":" + value);
}  

//Function to assign random values to the passed array
function makeArrayRandom(value, index, theArray) {
var maxSize = 5;
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxSize);
theArray[index] = randomNum;
console.log("Array[" + index + "]" + ":" + randomNum);    
}

//Function to create a copy of the random numbers array
function map(value, index, theArray) {
var arrayCopy = [];      
arrayCopy[index] = theArray[index];
console.log("Array[" + index + "]" + ":" + value); 
return arrayCopy;
}

//Function to compare the values of the array
function isNextGreater(value, index, theArray) {  
var size = theArray.length  

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {            
if (theArray[i] < theArray[i+1]){
   theArray[i] = -1;
} else {
   theArray[i] = 1;
}  
}

console.log("Array[" + index + "]" + ":" + value);            
} 

//Use ForEach to pass Array data to functions.                          
console.log("Display the Array:");
zeros.forEach(showArray);
console.log("Random Array:");
zeros.forEach(makeArrayRandom);
console.log("Copy of Zeros:");
zeros.forEach(map);
console.log("Is Next Greater:");
zeros.forEach(isNextGreater);

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: That's a pretty odd assignment. Instead of returning the last value itself, I'd expect to get an array that is one item shorter than the input.

Comment: You are not supposed to use a `for` loop inside the function that you use with `forEach`.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried using value before as well but I see now what I was doing wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `isNextGreater` function to this, and you are done.

```
function isNextGreater(value, index, theArray) {  
    var size = theArray.length  

    if (index < size - 1){
        if (value < theArray[index+1] ){
            value = -1;
        } else {
            value = 1;
        }  
    }else{
        value = value;
    }

    console.log("Array[" + index + "]" + ":" + value);            
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/v1hw1m0x/) is a fiddle to check the result (the result are displayed on the console)

Comment: You are right, that code can be improved by removing the last `else`statement